# Prove that $\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b-a}\ge e^{-a}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove that $\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b-a}\ge e^{-a}$.

I have a condition that $\frac{a}{b}\le1$ (don't know whether it is needed). Also, $b$ is integer, but $a$ is not.

My attempt: $\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b-a}=\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)}$

So, we need to prove that $\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1-\frac{a}{b}}\ge e^{-\frac{a}{b}}$

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: @Deif, $b$ is integer, $a$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $1-\frac{a}{b}=u$. Then we have $u\geq 0$ and that we want to show $u^u \geq e^{u-1}.$ Write $u^u$ as $e^{u\ln u}$. All you need to show is $u\ln u-u-1\geq 0$ for $u\geq 0$. See if you can take it from there!